# Rails many to many relationship and remote relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Suppose if we have the album, artist, and song model in rails.

In album:

```
class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :artist_album
  has_many :artist, :through => :artist_album
  has_many :song
```

In artistalbum:

```
class ArtistAlbum < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :album
  belongs_to :artist
end
```

In song:

```
class Song < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :artist_song
  has_many :artists, :through => :artist_song
  belongs_to :album
```

In artist:

```
class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :artist_song
  has_many :song, :through => :artist_song
```

Is it possible with active record to select the following record set:

- Find the album that belongs to the artist

Since artists are attached to songs, and albums are only sets of songs, and there is no direct relation from artist to album.

As well as selecting each of the songs belong to each of the albums for the artist in question

In essence something to this effect:

```
SELECT albums.`name`
FROM artists INNER JOIN artist_songs ON artists.id = artist_songs.artist_id
     INNER JOIN songs ON songs.id = artist_songs.song_id
     INNER JOIN albums ON songs.album_id = albums.id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you missing the `ArtistSong` model? And normally we use plural form in `has_many`, i.e. `has_many :artist_songs`.

If you have the `ArtistAlbum` join model, you do not need to go to the `Song` part...Just `artist.albums` if you have the following setup:

```
class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :artist_albums
  has_many :albums, :through => :artist_albums
end
```

The following are what you may use, but not necessarily required.

```
class ArtistAlbum < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :artist
  belongs_to :album
end

class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :artist_albums
  has_many :artist, :through => :artist_albums
end
```

Comment: Thanks, this got me started with a basic model!